# Steerable filters, conditions under which 2D functions are steerable.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm reading few papers about signal processing and the following theorem is stated.

> A function $f(x,y)$ steers when it can be written as
>   $$
> f^{\theta}(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^M k_j(\theta)f^{\theta_j}(x,y)
> $$

And the goal would be finding which functions admit such decomposition, and how many terms $M$ are required.

> **Theorem 1** : The steering condition  holds for functions expandable as
>   $$
> f(r,\phi) = \sum_{n=-N}^N a_n(r)e^{in\phi}
> $$
>   if and only if the interpolation functions $k_j(\theta)$ are solutions of
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}1 \\e^{i\theta} \\ \vdots \\ e^{iN\theta} \end{pmatrix} =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
> e^{i\theta_1} & e^{i\theta_2} & \ldots & e^{i\theta_M} & \\
> \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
> e^{iN\theta_1} & e^{iN\theta_2} & \ldots & e^{iN\theta_M}
> \end{pmatrix} 
> \begin{pmatrix} k_1(\theta) \\ k_2(\theta) \\ \vdots \\ k_M(\theta) \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Not sure about the proof of this theorem though, it's just few lines and basically it seems to me $f(r,\phi)$ substitutes both $f^{\theta}$ and $f^{\theta_j}$ in the steerable condition, we pick each component $m$ and from there we derive the linear system, is this the idea of the proof of this theorem?

The other theorem is the following

> **Theorem 2**: Let $T$ be the number of nonzero coefficients $a_n(r)$ for a function $f(r,\phi)$ expandable in the form above. Then, the minimum number of basis functions sufficient to steer $f(r,\phi)$ by
>   $$
> f^{\theta}(r,\phi) = \sum_{j=1}^{M} k_j(\theta)g_j(r,\phi)
> $$
>   is $T$, i.e. $M$ must be $\geq T$.

The proof of this theorem is similar to the former in the initial part, i.e. we substitute the expansion above to both $f^{\theta}$ and $g_j$, we later project into $e^{im\theta}$ for $0 \leq m \leq N$, and divide both sides by $a_m(r)$ which provides

$$
e^{im\theta} = \sum_{j=1}^M k_j(\theta)c_{jm}(r).
$$

From here not entirely sure how an equation of the form

$$
I = CKC^T
$$

is derived. The paper is [enter link description here](http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/freeman_steerable.pdf), and again the questions are if you can fill the bits of the proof of the two theorems.

**Update** (notation clarification) : From the paper

> Let $(\ldots)^{\theta}$ represent the rotation operator such that for any function $f(x,y)$, $f^{\theta}(x,y)$ is $f(x,y)$ rotated through an angle $\theta$ about the origin.

Comment: What does the notation $f^{\theta}$ mean?

Comment: @MPW, please see the update. I guess what this means is that you transform $(x,y)$ according to a rotation of an angle $\theta$. Section II of the paper provides an example.